# How would I use a protected variable instead of a 'global' in this class?

Tags: php, oop, global-variables

I have the following database query which works fine but in another question earlier, it was brought to my attention that I'm using a global, when it's not necessary. The reason for that was that I attempted to use a protected variable but being a new-comer to OOP, was unable to make it work.

Perhaps someone could show me how it should be done?

```
<?
class DB {

  public function __construct() {

    global $dbh;

    try {
      $dbh  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main_db', 'my_user', 'my_pass');
      $dbh  ->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function getFAQCats2Array() {

    global $dbh;

    try {
      $q = '
            SELECT
                `id`        AS ci,
                `name`      AS n
            FROM
                `faqcat`;
      ';

      $s = $dbh->query($q);

      // initialise an array for the results
      $A = array();

      while ($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $A[] = $r;
      }

      $s = null;
      return $A;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo  "Something went wrong fetching the list of FAQ categories from the database.\n";
      file_put_contents(
          $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
          "\n\n\n\n".$e->__toString(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
  }

  public function getFAQ($i, $f) {

      global $dbh;

       try {
        $q = '
            SELECT
                '.$f.'
            FROM
                faq
            WHERE
                id = ?
        ';

        $s = $dbh->prepare($q);
        $s->execute(array($i));
        //$s->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $r = $s->fetch();

        return $r[$f];

      }

      catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo  "Something went wrong fetching the FAQ answer from the database.\n";
        file_put_contents(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
            "\n\n\n\n".$e->__toString(), FILE_APPEND);

      }

  }

}
```

(There were other functions in the class using the same connection string in `$dbh`, but I've removed them for simplicities sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply strike the `global $dbh`!
Globals are usally a very bad idea and make your code harder to mantain.

In this case I recommend using a class property (which is kinda global, but ONLY in this class):

```
class DB
{
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = new PDO();
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return $this->dbh->query();
    }
}
```

I' ve stripped and simplifyed a lot of code here, but this should give you the idea of how class propertys work in general. You can also read a lot about this on the PHP.net Manual.

Comment: That's done the trick. I've certainly read a lot about it on php.net, but unfortunately, wasn't able to gain sufficient understanding of the concept there, for me to implement it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've just discovered that `$this->dbh->query($q);` works fine, but in another query which uses `$this->dbh->prepare($q);` it gave the error, "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object". What did I do wrong please?

Comment: How do you call the `prepare()` method. Without any piece of code I cannot help that well.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the affected function to the question (it's `getFAQ()`). The line with the error is `$s = $dbh->prepare($q);`. When I made it, `$s = $this->dbh->prepare($q);` just like the `query` I got the error. Those methods with `query` were ok though.

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($this->dbh); ?

Comment: I put it in just before `$s = $this->dbh->prepare($q);` in `getFAQ()` and got the following error; `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/peter/Documents/websites/Our_websites/project_1/main_site/public/inc/classes/db.class.php on line 33` Line 33 was 'var_dump($this->dbh);'

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `global $dbh`.

Just add a property to your DB class, for example `protected $db` and then put your PDO instance inside `$this->db` for you can use the `$db` var only inside the object. This is the basic way to use some kind of "Database Model" , where you can find plenty of tutorials through the web :)

For example :

```
public __construct($db_type = 'mysql', $host = 'my_server', $database = 'db_name', $user = 'my_user', $pwd = 'password') {
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;

    $dsn = $db_type.':host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . '';

    try {
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pwd, $pdo_options);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        'Unable to connect to database';
    }
}
```

And then make an instance of your object in the global scope, where you script uses it :

```
$db_manager = new DB('mysql','localhost','my_db','root','password');
```

And then your `$db_manager` will be able to use the public methods of your `DB` class

Answer (score 0):

There you go..

```
class DB {

  protected $dbh;

  public function __construct() {   

    try {
      $this->dbh  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main_db', 'my_user', 'my_pass');
      $this->dbh  ->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function getFAQCats2Array() {  

    try {
      $q = '
            SELECT
                `id`        AS ci,
                `name`      AS n
            FROM
                `faqcat`;
      ';

      $s = $this->dbh->query($q);

      // initialise an array for the results
      $A = array();

      while ($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $A[] = $r;
      }

      $s = null;
      return $A;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo  "Something went wrong fetching the list of FAQ categories from the database.\n";
      file_put_contents(
          $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
          "\n\n\n\n".$e->__toString(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add $this->dbh in the query method.